# How can I parse the expiration date from a Windows Azure SAS key as a client?

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I'm trying to check on the expiration date of the SAS key on the client side so that I can request a new SAS key once it expires.  I'm using the `Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage` namespace (which is version 2.0 of the azure storage library).  Is there a built in method for this or will I have to parse it manually?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't believe there's anything specific in the storage client library. You should be able to parse the querystring on the URI and look at the UTC date in `signedexpiry`. You can parse the querystring with [`HttpUtility.ParseQueryString()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh508996.aspx).

Here are two caveats to think about:

- This check won't be entirely accurate, since there could be clock-drift between your machine's clock and the Storage service's clock.
- If the server uses a shared access *policy* (which allows for programmatic modification/revocation of access), there's no guarantee that `signedexpiry` will be part of the querystring. More on shared access policies [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee393341.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

David's answer is correct for the question about how to parse the expiry time (+1).  But ultimately you should not be doing this.  There are two better options:

1. The client should attempt to access the resource and then handle the authentication failure by requesting a new SAS.
2. Provide a method for the client to determine the SAS expiry time, and the client would then keep track of this time and do a refresh at some interval before the expiry.  An example of this is shown at http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/2012/06/12/introducing-table-sas-shared-access-signature-queue-sas-and-update-to-blob-sas.aspx.